# Unity Multiple navmesh agents .

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, artificial-intelligence

Hello so im working on a RTS game so i will controll more then 1 minion but wen i trie and add another minion and command them both they go to the point and then they look at each other like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/331Mo.jpg. 
the code for the minions to move is this :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class moveTest : MonoBehaviour {

    NavMeshAgent navAgent;



    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        navAgent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();


    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        move();

    }
    void move()
    {
        RaycastHit hit;
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
        {
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 1000))
            {
                navAgent.SetDestination(hit.point);

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The agent will go as close as it can to the position. Since you're telling both to go to the same position, they push in as close as they can. You might want to increase the stopping distance or add a random.insideunitsphere to the hit.point so they look more like a group

Comment: can you explain like a example